# Showing two events are independent

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

```
We throw a pair of fair dice. Let A be the event that at least one dice
is a 3. Let B be the event that the sum of the two dice is 6.
(i) Compute the probability of A.
(ii) Compute the probability of B.
(iii) Are A and B independent? Explain your answer.
```

For part i, I calculated it to be P(A)=(2(1/6)(5/6)+(1/6)(1/6))=11/36

For part ii, I calculated it to be P(B)=(5(1/6)(1/6))=5/36

For part iii, how could I show that they're independent? I know that for independent events: p(A intersect B) = p(A)p(B) but I don't have p(A union B) to work out p(A intersect B).

Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: What outcomes are in $A\cap B$? Work this out directly.

Comment: Didn't think about it this way, would be (3,3), which means that P(A∩B)=(1/36)? Therefore, the events are not independent since 1/36 is not equal to 55/1296

Comment: Good! Now you are almost done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to work out $P(A\cap B)$ or $P(A\cup B)$. Since there are $36$ equiprobable elementary events, these probabilities must be multiples of $\frac1{36}$. Since $\frac{11}{36}\cdot\frac5{36}$ is not a multiple of $\frac1{36}$, the events are not independent.